# change mysql where_in query to codeigniters active record 

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

is it possible to right this query

```
`$sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM employers
    LEFT JOIN jobwall ON jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id
    WHERE employers.employer_id
    IN (SELECT employers_employer_id FROM jobwall)
';

$this->db->query($sql);`
```

as active-record in codeigniter

Comment: Not sure I follow the purpose of the `LEFT JOIN` to jobwall combined with the `WHERE...IN` clause. If employers.employer_id has to be `IN` that subquery, then couldn't you simply use an `INNER JOIN` instead?

Comment: could you show me what you mean please? However what I am trying to achieve is to show the company name and then the list of jobs associated to the company, doing an inner join shows the company name for each job that company has

Comment: Your subquery selects the same column you're using for the join condition, `employers_employer_id`. If the employers.employer_id has to be `IN` that subquery, you've effectively turned the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. So, I think the query could be simplified to just: `SELECT * FROM employers INNER JOIN jobwall ON jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id`

Comment: The problem with this is that I might have multiple entries from the employer in the jobwall table which means it would show the employer multiple times, I only want to show the employer once and then list jobs for that employer

Comment: @sea_1987:I have given active record query for where...in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Joe Stefanelli, the LEFT JOIN and the WHERE IN subquery are unnecessary with a normal join. The following should do what you want:

```
$this->db->join('jobwall'
    , 'jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id');
$this->db->get('employers');
```

You would use a LEFT JOIN only if you wanted to get all employers whether or not they were in the jobwall table.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for same. Then got appropriate answer.

```
$this->db->select('employers_employer_id');
$this->db->from('jobwall');

$subquery = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();
$subquery = str_replace("\n"," ",$subquery);

$this->db->where_in('tag_page_id', $subquery, false); //false=if no escape for subquery 
$this->db->join('jobwall', 'jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id','left');
$this->db->get('employers');
```